# Как запустить через child_process.spawn локально установленную библиотеку?

Tags: node.js

Я хочу программно запустить Electron-приложение через `child_process.spawn`:

```
import ChildProcess, {ChildProcess as ChildProcess__type} from 'child_process';
const childProcess: ChildProcess__type = ChildProcess.spawn(
        'electron',
        ['ProjectInitializer__ElectronMain.js'],
        { cwd: __dirname } // корень текущего проекта
    );
```

У меня возникает ошибка `Error: spawn electron ENOENT`. Electron установлен локально, что, насколько я знаю, вполне нормально.

Следуя [инструкции](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27688805/4818123) по отладке данной ошибки, я добрался до описанной там причины: среди `process.env.PATH` отсутствует директория, в которой находится приложение `electron`. Я об этой переменной знаю мало, а потому, что там должно быть, а что не должно - не могу ответить. Но вопрос у меня такой: а как же тогда запускать локально установленные приложения из `node_modules?` проекта? Вроде бы вполне типовая задача...

Кстати, в библиотека [execa](https://github.com/sindresorhus/execa), которая позиционируется как улучшенный child-process, прекрасно всё запускает (обновление: версия 2.0.0 уже не запускает):

```
import executeExternalCommand, { ExecaReturnValue } from 'execa';

try {
  await executeExternalCommand(
      'electron',
      ['ProjectInitializer__ElectronMain.js'],
      { cwd: __dirname }
  );
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Версия 1.x.x почему-то по `{ cwd: __dirname }` знает, где искать electron (версия 2.x.x уже не знает). К сожалению, документации по этой библиотеке и мало, а потому я не могу найти решения таких элементарных задач, как вывод данных в консоль из дочернего процесса или передача данных в дочерний процесс.

Comment: Можно ж через require сделать - без запуска отдельного процесса?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Не совсем понимаю, как это через require программно запустить electron-приложение, но в любом случае нужно разобраться с задачей запуска в дочернем процессе приложения, находящегося в node_module - electron или любого другого.